# If something doesn't itch, it shouldn't be scratched

Tags: meaning

> *If something doesn't itch, it shouldn't be scratched*

What does this sentence mean? Is it an idiom or something else?

Does it mean: Don’t poke in small problems that will lead to serious one?

Comment: It's not really an "idiom" - it's a mangled version of the standard *If it ain't broke, don't fix it* (as noted by @Cathy below). But it doesn't actually work very well, since obviously if something ***is*** broke[n], it would be a good idea to fix it - but even if something does itch, the standard advice is still *Don't scratch!* (or you risk getting a nasty infection). Using the cited version may not mark you out as a non-native speaker, but it will certainly make some people think you say some strange things that don't make a lot of sense on closer examination.

Comment: @Laila Yes, it does. In an effort to have everything perfect, a mistake might be made that will lead to a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't rock the boat. / Leave well enough alone. / If it ain't broke, don't fix it. 
In other words, don't try to fix a small problem, because you may end up with a bigger one.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning:Don't go looking for trouble or problems-let them come to you.If there is no evidence of a real problem, and fixing the "problem" would not effectively improve the situation,then don't waste time and energy (yours or anybody else's) trying to fix it.Allow something to stay as it is because doing more would not improve it.Do not disturb a situation as it is - since it would result in trouble or complications.Do not try to change something lest you make it worse.

You can use the following idioms to convey the same meaning:

1.Let sleeping dogs lie.

2.leave well enough alone(Also, let well enough alone.)
 For example, This recipe has turned out fine in the past, so leave well enough alone. The idea behind this expression dates from ancient Greek times, specifically Aesop's fable about a fox who refused a hedgehog's offer to take out its ticks lest, by removing those that are full, other hungry ones will replace them. Put as let well alone from the early 1700s, it was first recorded as let well enough alone in 1827.

3.Don't trouble trouble until trouble troubles you.

4.If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

5.Don't rock the boat (Definition:don’t cause any disturbance, don’t try to change anything, don’t mess up the situation, don’t do anything drastic, keep things as they are, stay normal and calm, don’t make anyone upset.)

Now lets take a look at the origin of the sentence in your question:

We all know that scratching an itch makes it worse.Have you ever wondered why that might be? Of course, a bunch of scientists have, and they think they’ve cracked it.scratching causes the brain to release your “happy hormone” serotonin, which actually makes the itch worse.While serotonin helps alleviate pain in the brain, it also eventually spreads to the spinal cord. From there, it moves from pain-sensing neurons to neurons that influence itch intensity, making itching worse.